# Ajax don't send file

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to do a solution in Ajax to send a file when the user send a file and upload automatically when change the status

Code

```
<script>
function filePassSelected() {
    var data = $('frmpass')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(data);
    alert (formData);
        $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        success:function(data){
            $('#verdoc').html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
};
</script>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmpass">
  <label for="fileToUploadPass" class="btn" id="labelfilesid">
    <div class="buttonfile" style="margin:auto">National ID</div>
  </label>
  <input id="fileToUploadPass" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file" name="fileToUploadPass" onchange="filePassSelected()">
</form>
<div id="verdoc"></div>
```

Otherwise, the form is not sending `data`, I change `data` in the Ajax to send random information and works, but if send the file don't work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: the ```data``` should be something like ```var data = $('#fileToUploadPass')[0];```

Comment: var data = $('#frmpass')[0];

Comment: Raman, thanks! This solved my other problem! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add contentType and processData as false

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        success:function(data){
            $('#verdoc').html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }});
```

Comment: solved the problem of sending the form, thanks! However, it still does not send the file, my PHP returns `Notice: Undefined index: fileToUploadPass` ... I believe it may be an error in the javascript `var data = $ ('frmpass') [0]` but I'm not able to fix it ... could that be that the origin of the error?

Comment: as suggested by Raman I forget the # in `var data = $('#frmpass')[0];`, and now is working! Thank you very much guys!

Comment: if frmpass is id then u should write #frmpass if it is class then u should write as .frmpass

Comment: Yes! Total lack of attention is such a simple mistake, thank you very much for your help!